# How to dismiss slide menu and link back to selected tab?

Tags: ios, objective-c, tabbar

I have slide menu view controller and first item is "Home" option. What I want to do is when I click on "Home" option, app will redirect to 1st tab which is Home page even at Category Tab.

Now only slide menu hides when I click on "Home" option but tab still remain at Category Tab

Below is my sample code in Menu View Controller:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    if (indexPath.row == 0) { // HOW CAN I CLICK ON MENU ITEM 1 AND LINK BACK TO TAB NUMBER 1?

       [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ 
           [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0]; }];

    }
```

[image]

Comment: try to set selected tabcontroller before dismissing.

Comment: @MRizwan33 the dismiss for the MenuVC not the tab

Comment: Hi MRizwan33, tried before, not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {  

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{ 

       UITabBarController*roo = (UITabBarController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

       roo.selectedIndex = 0;
   }];

}
```

Comment: Hi Sh_Khan, awesome! your solution is work. Thanks for your help!